# WordPress WPDB user error

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I recently started using WPDB class in function for an Ajax call.
I have a function that already works fine (so not my first time doing it), but this one is giving me some trouble.

Here is the code (just for the record, but you can skip it):

```
$rev = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT DISTINCT main.ID
    FROM $wpdb->posts main
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta keyState
    ON keyState.post_id = main.ID
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta keyCity
    ON keyCity.post_id = main.ID
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta keyTipo
    ON keyTipo.post_id = main.ID
    WHERE main.post_status LIKE 'publish'
        && main.post_type LIKE 'revendedores'
        && keyState.meta_key LIKE 'state'
        && keyState.meta_value LIKE %s
        && keyCity.meta_key LIKE 'city'
        && keyCity.meta_value LIKE %s
        && keyTipo.meta_key LIKE 'tipo'
        && keyTipo.meta_value LIKE '%loco%'
    ORDER BY main.post_title ASC
", $state, $city) );
```

PS: I checked the query in phpMyAdmin, it is correct. Should return (for now) only one ID (96), but the result is empty. The $state and $city variables are also set anc correct.

So I activated the error debugging with $wpdb->show_errors(); and tried $wpdb->print_error(); and nothing showed up.

Any idea how to solve it?

Note: I tried $wpdb->get_results(...) and got the same results.